# Bigquery service account restricted to a dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it possible to create a bigquery service account to limit access to only 1 dataset? When I go through the service account generation process it appears to give access to an entire project and does not show options to limit to a specific data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes.  But to do it you do not assign the privileges at the project level.  You need to actually go and modify the dataset to do it.
Check the documentation here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls

It outlines the process with a few different methods.

Comment: You have to grant the service account on the specific resource, the dataset. In the IAM page, you grant the service account on the project. Therefore, go to BigQuery, select a dataset, go to permission and grant the service account on it.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere is it possible to have clear tutorial how to do it?